# Localhost error PHP codeigniter 4 local host running error

Tags: php

I have complete coding in PHP Codeignitor 4 for inserting data into database, but whenever i try to access localhost its giving error.

i changed my base url too but nothing working...

i have project name ci4_crud then app and subfolders i m using different links like localhost/insert or localhost/ci4_crud/app/views/insert  but nothing working ...

in App.php my base url is http://localhost/ci4_crud/

can someone help me plz

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
<head>
<title> Registration Form </title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?=base_url() ?> Crud/savedata">
<table border="1" width="600">
  <tr>
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter First Name">
  </tr>
  <tr>
<input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
  </tr>
  <tr>
<input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter Address">
  </tr>
  <tr>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email ID">
  </tr>
  <tr>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save Data">
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following rule in public/.htaccess on line 17:

```
RewriteBase /ci4_crud
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>crud/savedata"
```

or this

```
action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index/crud/savedata"
```

and also may I know what error message you get.